# Como permitir que uma expressão regular de letras e números aceite o cedilha

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Preciso que a expressão regular aceite a tecla ***ç*** cedilha.

```
$('[name="txtEndereco"]').keyup(function () { 
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/g,''); 
});
```

Comment: `/[^a-zA-ZçÇ 0-9]+/g`?

Comment: Seria algo assim? `'çedilh!a'.replace(/[^A-zÀ-ÿ\s\d]/, ''); // dá çedilha`

Comment: Desta forma funcionou ''replace(/[^a-zA-ZçÇ 0-9]+/g,'');'' @Sergio.

Comment: Marque a resposta dele como sendo a resposta correta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/[^a-zA-ZçÇ 0-9]+/g
```

Trabalhar com regex em letras com acentos é +/- dificil em JavaScript.

Noutras linguagens há a classe `\p{L}` que inclui todos os caracteres que sejam letras. Em JavaScript às vezes o melhor é adicionar os casos que são precisos.

Answer (score 1):

Usando [À-ú] pega cedilha, tio, acento grave, acento agudo, acento circunflexo etc. Eu tive problemas e usei essa expressão, funcionou muito bem.